# How can pipulated file from tree structure in java

Tags: java

Im trying to fill up a tree with the entries from a text file and I can read the file and I know how to make a tree object. I just dont know how to combine these two to populate the tree.
Thanks in advance. I am the new for java, any idea may be help me.

Comment: If you know how to read things out of a file, and you know how to put things into your data structure, then surely that's the whole thing solved!

Answer (score 1):

As you know, a tree is a graph without cycles. Or, if you say one is a root node, a graph where every node has zero or more children and exactly one parent (except for the root node).

In order to create a tree from a file, you have to define the nodes and their relationships. Since the "parent" relationship is the easiest (each node has exactly one parent, except for the root node which has zero parents), you should somehow get the parent for each node from the file.

In short: for each node from the text file, create a node in the tree. Check what the parent node should be, find it in your existing tree. Add the new node as a child to the parent node.

Unless you post some additional info about the text file, this is as far as I can help you.